# How can I auto import html from web site?

Tags: java, javascript, c#, html, visual-studio-2010

I would like to know how can I automatically pull html from web site and put it into eclipse or visual studio. I would like my program to pull it from internet on every five minutes or so. Also can my program autoclick on some buttons or refresh the page?

Comment: Visual Studio: Tools > Options > Environment > Startup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need http://www.seleniumhq.org/ - it can download source of the page and you can programmatically click on links and perform other interactions with the page

Also you can download web pages with Apache HTTP Client library - http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html